How to replace href in document body using javascript
How can I replace the URL below which is appearing in document body using javascript?
<a id="some_random_id" tabindex="0" onfocus="return HyperlinkBox.OnFocus(this, event);" onblur="return HyperlinkBox.OnBlur(this, event);" style="vertical-align:middle;TEXT-DECORATION: underline;overflow:hidden;padding:5px;text-overflow:ellipsis;display:inline-block;" target="_blank" title="http://oldserver/sites/mysite/Lists/Attendance/NewEditForm.aspx?ID=100" href="http://oldserver/sites/mysite/Lists/Attendance/NewEditForm.aspx?ID=100" class="">Click here to upload file</a>

I want to replace http://oldserver with https://newserver
If I use document.body.innerHTML to replace then it does the job but breaks page.

You need to select the a element from the DOM first, then update its href property. The body isn't what you need.

I've marked 2 duplicates. The first shows you how to find the a element and set its href value, the second one shows you how to replace text within a string. As a side note, please be aware that you should not be using onfocus, onblur or any of the other on* HTML attributes. Bind your event handlers in JS only, not HTML.
